# I'm having trouble parsing HTML table into csv

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the table from 
http://www.sec.gov/divisions/enforce/friactions.shtml and turn into csv.

I used this code

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('litigation.csv', 'wb') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  for i in range(39):
    url = "http://www.sec.gov/divisions/enforce/friactions.shtml".format(i)
    u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    try:
        html = u.read()
    finally:
        u.close()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find("table", {"cellspacing" : "7"})
    for tr in table.find_all('tr')[2:]:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

But when I use this, the result is bizarre.

I intended to crawl all the table, but only the contents up to `sep 4` is recorded in the csv file.
Besides, the contents are duplicated several times(i guess it's about 3 times) and make the row longer than I intended.

Can anyone help solving this problem?

Comment: This `"http://www.sec.gov/divisions/enforce/friactions.shtml".format(i)` gives always the same URL - you forgot `{}` in text - so you read the same page many times.

Comment: THX for ur help, I resolved this problem
I'm now trying to solve why the table stops on the half of the table - maybe what I found as table location might be wrong ;-(

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing the [differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers):

```
In [8]: rows = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find("table", {"cellspacing" : "7"}).find_all('tr')[2:]

In [9]: len(rows)
Out[9]: 29

In [10]: rows = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib").find("table", {"cellspacing" : "7"}).find_all('tr')[2:]

In [11]: len(rows)
Out[11]: 97

In [12]: rows = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml").find("table", {"cellspacing" : "7"}).find_all('tr')[2:]

In [13]: len(rows)
Out[13]: 97
```

In other words, `html.parser` does not handle this particular HTML well, use `html5lib` or `lxml`.

See also:

- [Installing a parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)